# Connection Two sites

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, switch, site-to-site-vpn

My office is moving and the big concern is about networking. The move will take two months but they need both sides to be operational during that time. The big challenge is our old PBX. Do they need phone connectivity in both offices for these couple of months?
If we get a temporary internet provider for the new site can we connect the two modems with a VPN? Will that connection make the PBX work in the second office?

Answer (score 1):

> if we get a temporary internet provider for the new site can we connect the two modems with a VPN?

You'll need some device that can do VPN. This can be two PC's with pfsense installed, or dedicated hardware from e.g. Juniper or Cisco. If you have zero expirience with routers, it's advisable to hire a contractor who knows networking.

> will that connection make the pbx work in the second office?

If the PBX uses routable TCP/IP protocols then yes.

Comment: No, I hear you we will definitely hire a contractor .. Just wanted to have a general idea of what are my options are. Thank you for your answer